# Distribution function of the random variable $X\cdot\mathbf 1_{X>K}$ with $K>0$

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be a non-negative random variable and $K$ be a fixed positive number. Consider 
$$
    Y= 
\begin{cases}
    X,& \text{if } X>K\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Also, assume that $P(X>K)=p$. Then how do we find the distribution function of $Y$?

Here, I tried to use the following idea, but I think this idea does not work.
Let $P$ and $Q$ be two random variables and $$
    W= 
\begin{cases}
    P,& \text{with prob.} =p\\
    Q,& \text{with prob.} =1-p             
\end{cases}
$$
Then, $F_{W}(x)=pF_{P}(x)+(1-p)F_{Q}(x)$.

I also know that $E[Y]=E[X|X>K]P(X>K)$, but I was unable to find $F_{Y}(x)$.

Comment: "Let X be a non-negative random variable"


You need to say more about what sort of random variable it is.

Comment: It could be any, like loss random variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Use the definition of $F_Y$.

$$F_Y(x)=P(Y\leq x).$$

If $x<0$, $(Y\leq x)=\emptyset$. Hence $F_Y(x)=0$. If $0\leq x\leq K$, $(Y\leq x)=(X\leq K)$. Hence $F_Y(x)=P(X\leq K)=1-P(X>K)=1-p$. When $x>K$, $(Y\leq x)=(X\leq x)$. Hence $F_Y(x)=F_X(x)$.

Comment: This is not the case $(Y≤x)=(X≤K)$ for $0≤x≤K$, instead $(Y≤x)=0$ for $0≤x≤K$.

Comment: $(Y\leq x)=(X\leq K)$ means the event $(Y\leq x)$ happens if and only if the event $(X\leq K)$ happens.